# sort SQL data in xcode

Tags: ios, sql, sorting

I am trying to sort / order SQL data in my iOS app. the database is working fine. i can add data, display in tableview, edit, delete everything is working fine. just can't sort.  below is the code i am using.

```
    -(void)sortTable
    {
    //CHECKING DIRECTORY AND CREATING DATABASE CODE STARTS

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths [0];

    //Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"events.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_eventDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT TEXT, EVENTDATE TEXT)";

            //closing database after creating
            if (sqlite3_exec(_eventDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //  sqlite3_close(_eventDB);
            }
        }
    }
    //CHECKING DIRECTORY AND CREATING DATABASE CODE ENDS




   //sort sql table

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

       if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_eventDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *sortSQLTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT EVENT FROM EVENTS ORDER BY EVENT"]; // EVENTS is the table name and EVENT is the column.

            const char *sort_stmt = [sortSQLTable UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(_eventDB, sort_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        }

    }
```

I am executing this void statement in viewDidLoad.

I have searched a lot. tried different things. just could not make it work. can someone help please.

**UPDATE:**

I just found that the ORDER BY query is actually sorting the table, but its not saving the database.

any idea how i can save the database after sorting?

Comment: Can you give some more details? E.g. which data structure are you using to fill the DB data into?

Comment: thanks for your reply Koray Alkan. not sure what exactly you asked, i have edited my question with the code that i am using to create the table.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you load the data into table and save it?

Comment: @Koray Alkan,  
after you ask for the code where i load the data into the table, i looked into my code and found the problem. During loading data into the table, i was using  @"SELECT * FROM EVENTS”. As soon as i change the code to @"SELECT * FROM EVENTS ORDER BY EVENT” it started to work. actually i don’t have to save the table after sort, just have to display it.  
Thank you very much for the clue. you saved my day :-)

Comment: glad you've found it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sort data to display on your tableview you could use a [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[Here is the documentation from Apple on how to use them.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE)

The gist though is something like ..

```
//array of People objects with properties of firstName and lastName just for example
NSArray *firstNames = @[ @"Jan", @"Steve", @"Jay", @"Mike" ];
NSArray *lastNames = @[ @"Joker", @"Jones", @"Smith", @"Pham" ];

NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
[firstNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
    person.firstName = [firstNames objectAtIndex:idx];
    person.lastName = [lastNames objectAtIndex:idx];
    [people addObject:person];
}];

//make the descriptor
NSSortDescriptor *firstNameSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" 
  ascending:YES ];

//sort the array using the descriptor
NSLog(@"By first name: %@", [people sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[firstNameSortDescriptor]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Alicia Cano. sorting only the tableView causes more problem. when i am tapping to edit a cell data, its actually editing a different row in the sqlite database, because the order of the table in tableView is different from the table in SQL database.